# php class method not showing all rows if reference more than one method

Tags: php, class

I am trying to move over to OOP and have a User class with the following:

```
<?php 

    class User {

        public function __construct($sdb) 
        {
             $this->sdb = $sdb;
        }

        // and some other methods

    }

?>
```

I call the class using:

```
$Users = new User($sdb);
```

I can then use 
    echo $Users->GetAdminName($AdminId);

And it shows me the results just fine.

But then further down the page, I call another method named ShowUsers that returns all users from the table.

```
$results = $Users->ShowUsers();
foreach($results as $result)
{
 echo my results ....
}
```

The issue I am having is that the ShowUsers() method is only showing 1 record instead of all the records.

**BUT**, if I comment out the top method call

```
//echo $Users->GetAdminName($AdminId);
```

It shows all the records and not just one.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function GetAdminName($AdminId)
{
$this->sdb->limit_val="0,1";
$results = $this->sdb->dbSelect("administrators",array("AdminId","FirstName","LastName"),array("AdminId"=>$AdminId));
foreach($results as $result)
{ 
    $AdminName = $result["FirstName"]." ".$result["LastName"]; 
}
return $AdminName;
```

}

```
function ShowUsers($Status = '')
{
$this->sdb->order_by_column="LastName";
$tables=array("administrators", "roles");
$joins=array("administrators.RoleId=roles.RoleId");
$join_condition=array("INNER JOIN");
$columns=array("AdminId", "AdminEmail", "FirstName", "LastName", "Status", "RoleName");
if($Status)
{
$whereCondition=array("Status"=>"$Status");
}
return $this->sdb->dbSelectJoin($tables,$joins,$join_condition,$columns,$whereCondition);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the GetAdminName() and/or ShowUsers() code? Maybe in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Why jsfiddle?  Why not just here? its php code.

Comment: I just updated it with my methods, thanks.

Comment: `$this->sdb->limit_val`  needs to be reset...

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I would not think that the second method I call can bring over that option from another method.

Comment: Remember that you're dealing with the instantiations of an object, you need to make sure that your side-effects are managed.

Comment: @Scott: Well, the option shouldn't be carried over, I don't now _what_ database abstraction you're using, but maybe it's time to fix it ;)

Comment: I was thinking maybe because I pass the $sdb to the constructor so that I can use $this-> makes that option available if I run it once?